# c++ Template specialization with derived class

Tags: c++, templates

I am having problems trying to specialize a template method of a class to accept a derived class. I've tried with pointers as well and end up with many more issues than this iteration.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Json {
  public:
    Json(){}
    virtual ~Json(){}
    template <class T>
    bool Get(std::string key, T& value);
};

template <class T>
bool Json::Get(std::string key, T& value){
    std::cout << "Call default GET" << std::endl;
}

template <>
bool Json::Get(std::string key, Json& value){
    std::cout << "Call JSON GET" << std::endl;
}

class JsonError : public Json {
    public:
        JsonError(){}
        ~JsonError(){}
};

int main()
{
    // OK
    int int_value = 0;
    Json json;
    json.Get("int", int_value);
    
    // OK
    Json json_value;
    json.Get("json", json_value);
    
    // NOT OK
    JsonError json_error_value;
    json.Get("error", json_error_value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This should print out

```
Call default GET                                                                                                                                            
Call JSON GET                                                                                                                                               
Call JSON GET
```

Comment: Template type deduced arguments will always be more precise than something requiring any implicit casts (such as `JsonError&` to `Json&`), and thus will always be resolved as the better overload during overload resolution. You could work around this, but it might be easier to rethink the desired API

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9987fb4a2ec7c3a  What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @Human-Compiler That doesn't happen here.  `T` gets deduced as `JsonError` which means the specialization for `Json` is not used and the default template is called, at least in a conforming compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think OP means that the desired output is `JSON GET`, but that's not what the program does.

Comment: Okay I see. I thought maybe using pointers would also give a hint on which template to use.

Comment: @NathanOliver OP wants the last call to print `Call JSON GET`, there is no error, but current output for last call is `Call default GET`

Comment: @NathanOliver That's what I was trying to say... I probably could have worded that better.

Comment: Aha.  If that's what they want, they need to overload the function, not specialize it.  By and large, function template specializations are not what you want and instead you should overload as specializations are not actual functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how templates work. Template deduction is always on the exact type, in this case `JsonError`, so the specialization for `Json&` is not matched.

If you still want to make it work, you can overload the template function with a member function taking `Json&`. The template function will still be a better match for a derived type, so we also need to disable the template method for any type deriving from `Json`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Json {
  public:
    Json(){}
    virtual ~Json(){}
    template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Json, T>, int> = 0>
    bool Get(std::string key, T& value);

    bool Get(std::string key, Json& value);
};

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Json, T>, int> = 0>
bool Json::Get(std::string key, T& value){
    std::cout << "Call default GET" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool Json::Get(std::string key, Json& value){
    std::cout << "Call JSON GET" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

class JsonError : public Json {
    public:
        JsonError(){}
        ~JsonError(){}
};

int main()
{
    // OK
    int int_value = 0;
    Json json;
    json.Get("int", int_value);
    
    // OK
    Json json_value;
    json.Get("json", json_value);
    
    // NOW IT'S OK
    JsonError json_error_value;
    json.Get("error", json_error_value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to C++11 but that's a cool answer.

Comment: @ony_pox232 actually the code in the asnwer uses c++17, but nothing that could not also be done in c++11. For question that are not about the current standard you better use the tag for the specific version of the standard